# MongoDB filter by array property only if it exists

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

My database object has an optional property named `tags` which is a string array. I want to write a query that returns objects if they match one of these conditions:

1. They don't have a `tags` property.
2. They have a tags property that has at least one item included in another array called `queryTags`

From reading the documentation I came up with the following but it doesn't work:

```
let query = {
    tags: { '$or': [{'$exists': false}, {'$in': queryTags}]}
}
```

Comment: Try this `db.collection.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      tags: {
        "$exists": false
      }
    },
    {
      tags: {
        "$in": queryTags
      }
    }
  ]
})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$or` is a top-level operator, so your query needs to be:

```
let query = {
    '$or': [{tags: {'$exists': false}}, {tags: {'$in': queryTags}}]
}
```